# Force InfoPath form to open in Client

Tags: 2010, infopath, custom-list

I have a custom list that I need to open in the client. (I'm using a web service data connection and I get the 'loopback' error in the browser.) I do not see the option in the Library Settings to disallow opening in browser.

Is this not possible with a custom list? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I not sure I understand what you mean by opening a custom list in the client. What client are you looking to open a list with? If it's InfoPath, that's specific to InfoPath form libraries, not custom lists.

Comment: I customized the form of a Custom List in InfoPath with the thought that users could complete the form in the InfoPath client/filler.

Comment: What is the "loopback" error?  You receive this when opening the page form a client machine or just the server (b/c there is a fix for that).  It seems odd you can open the page, but receive the error when accessing web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SharePoint list form customized with InfoPath will always open in the browser, not in the client.

Only InfoPath filler forms can be opened in the client (Filler). A list form cannot be turned into a filler form.